# Classification of $E_6$ symmetry breaking

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, symmetry-breaking, unified-theories

Is there a good reference which details the various ways of breaking $E_6$ into smaller groups using Wilson lines? I'm looking for a list of discrete (Abelian) symmetries, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_5$, and the associated groups of rank 6 that $E_6$ is broken into, e.g. $SU(3) \times SU(2)\times U(1)^3$.

Comment: I find the remark under the question a bit confusing. You are asking for a reference, but the answer cannot be a reference. So what do you expect? I am assuming you are talking about the so-called discrete Wilson line (in the old string model building terminology). The group theory for these breakings can be found e.g. in [this paper](http://inspirehep.net/record/617797?ln=en) and [that paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0306049). Hard to give more details in a comment but cannot write an answer either since copying all the tables from these papers here seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: Hi @marmot - apologies for the confusion but I was just asking for a book or a paper which would contain details of these Wilson line breakings of $E_6$.  With that being said, thanks for the references in your comments.

Comment: I do not think it is your fault. (But indeed I have major problems understanding the policy on this particular site. In particular, I do not understand what should be in an answer. Clearly, if you don't know what $E_6$ is, you won't understand the question nor the answer. This raises the question of which background one should assume.)